# Kibana Query results missing data

Tags: kibana, kibana-7

I am running a kibana query from postman. Exact same query in Kibana Discover tab returns 49 rows of records. But, in postman, i can only see few results.

I can see hits as 49 but the array does not contain 49 elements.

"hits": {
"total": {
"value": 49,
"relation": "eq"
},
"max_score": 0.0,

[image: Results Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
  "size": 500,
```

should be added above the query field. It returns all the values